# Как сделать так, что бы функция повторялась

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
 $(document).ready(function exp(){
          if (window.innerWidth <= 576) {
             $('.Onf').on('click', function () {
             $('.Onf').fadeOut(100);
             $('.nav-burger').css('background-image', 'url("img/icon-menu.svg")', 'no-repeat'); 
             });
          }
    });
```

При клике на li-шку скрывает менюшку, и все бы ничего, только он срабатывает один раз... Как его зациклить, что бы без перезагрузки страницы срабатывал постоянно, или что-то в это духе....

Comment: Проверять имеет смысл при изменении размеров окна. Соответственно, код этот нужно поместить в обработчик события изменения размеров окна

Comment: @Regent разве нельзя поместить все в цикл после условия?

Comment: @Regent поместил, но скрипт ведь срабатывает только один раз, после нужно перезагружать страницу...А нужно как-то сделать, чтобы срабатывал все время без перезагрузки страницы...

Comment: можно обрабатывать событие resize например

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич в какой цикл и зачем?

Comment: @101 зачем проверять всё время, отъедая ресурсы компьютеров пользователей? Произошло изменение размеров окна - выполнили необходимую логику

Comment: @Grundy не надо восстанавливать Regent меня достал

Comment: Так она так и работает, только ты ее же и скрываешь ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Вызывается при загрузке и изменении ширины экрана

```
$(window).on("load resize", funtion(){
    $('.Onf').off('click');
    if (window.innerWidth <= 576) {
        $('.Onf').on('click', function(){
            $('.Onf').fadeOut(100);
            $('.nav-burger').css('background-image', 'url("img/icon-menu.svg")', 'no-repeat'); 
        });
    }
});
```

Как и Grundy отметил правильно

> Что в этом случае при изменении размеров до `576px`
>   будет добавлено куча обработчиков

Comment: стоит добавить, что в этом случае при изменении размеров до 576px будет добавлено куча обработчиков

Comment: @Grundy согласен но он же хотель повторение ну вот и повторяетсья.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов может, вместо цитаты в ответе поправить код, чтобы обработчиков не становилось много? Самый простой вариант - добавить `$('.Onf').off('click');` перед if-ом

Comment: @Regent почему вместо цитаты подсказал я написал автора не быть же мне плагиатором.